# How to control default zooming of webview on touching textFields

Tags: android, android-webview

I am loading .html file on Android Webview. That htmnl file contains textFields. So as the user taps over textfield our webview is getting zoom in. As a result my webpage getting widened (out of content )
I am using the code as:

```
    WebSettings webSettings = m_webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webSettings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
```

Please let me know if anything i am missing.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your html:

It's also a good idea to add the next settings to your webview.

```
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.setInitialScale(1);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code in order to set zooming controls in your app

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```